# If no additional directory in the install_name of a dynamic library, then which path does dyld search?

Tags: macos, dyld, dynamic-library, install-name-tool

Mac, for a compiled project (using QT 5.5.0), I directly run the executable file, the error:

libraw.10.dylib not loaded;

OK, I know the reason.

One solution is to use install_name_tool to change the install name of libraw.10.dylib and put it in somewhere, like in the article:
["Qt for OS X - Deployment"](https://web.archive.org/web/20181205033451/http://doc.qt.io:80/qt-5/osx-deployment.html)

But right now I don't want to do this way.
One reason is that I do not need to really deploy it; so I want to make it simpler by only copying the library "libraw.10.dylib" to the right place.
The second reason is that I am curious what the default path for an install name without additional directory.

But no matter where I put the file "libraw.10.dylib", the same error comes out.

I tried to look into the details in the [man page of dyld](https://web.archive.org/web/20160409091449/https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/dyld.1.html),
I couldn't figure it out.

Maybe all path variables are empty (I tried several popular variables, such as DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH, DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH, etc; they are empty).

Then I put the library "libraw.10.dylib" on the root, parallel to the folder "Applications". Still the same error.

So what dyld is looking for when it encounters:
libraw.10.dylib